# Bootstrap twitter CSS fails in gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I used Bootstrap Twitter to HTML format a digest email.

Formatting looks fine in Mail (Mac email client) but when I check my gmail from my browser, formatting doesn't apply, so it doesn't look too nice.

Any idea why this happens?

My email layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
      <link href='http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  </head>
  <body id='email'>
      <div class="container">
            <%= yield %>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

digest.html.erb

```
     <div class="row">
       <div class="span4">...</div>
     </div>
       ...
```

The bootstrap twitter CSS formatting from digest.html.erb doesn't apply or show when viewing in Gmail. Formatting does look good in my Mail (mac) email client.

Source from email in gmail:

```
----==_mimepart_4f71da44a148b_612e3fe48e034ec4200f0
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2012 17:18:28 +0200
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-ID: <4f71da44b71dc_612e3fe48e034ec4202ee@joel-maranhaos-macbook-pro.local.mail>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content=3D'text/html; charset=3DUTF-8' http-equiv=3D'Content-Ty=pe' />
  <link href=3D'http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap=.css' rel=3D'stylesheet' />
 </head>
  <body id=3D'email'>
                =


    <div class=3D"container">
      <br/>
    ....\
```

I notice all these 3D prefixes and some random = in the text, but I don't believe this is the problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: `3D` is the hex ASCII code for the `=` symbol. Given that, it looks like some kind of character-escaping going on in ERB or some plugin that is working in tandem with ERB? Try changing file name extension to `digest.text.html.erb`? Note how even the `=` embedded in a string (`content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'`) is being escaped.

Answer (score 4):

read [this article](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) which explains that the `<head>` is often ignored by email clients. Generally you want to include all styles inside the body tag, preferably by applying them to each element

i.e

```
<p style="font-family:pupcat;text-size:15px;line-height:19px;">Blah</p>
```

you should fix those typos too, they will not help you